# Qt Creator asks me to configure a compiler

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm running Debian 7, 32 bits. I've downloaded Qt here: http://qt-project.org/downloads

I took the link "Qt Online Installer for Linux 32-bit (22 MB) ". I then installed Qt, it worked but when I want to build a project, I get this error:

`Qt Creator needs a compiler set up to build. Connfigure a compiler in the kit options.`

I searched but I can't find how to solve this issue...

Comment: Try to apt-get install build-essential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you have a C++ compiler installed on your system and than in Qt Creator you go to *Tools->Options->Build & Run->Kits* and make sure that the kit has a compiler selected.

Comment: There's actually no compiler listed in "Kits". But that's weird, when I installed Qt on Windows I did not have to manually install a compiler.

Comment: On Windows the "MinGW" version of Qt is an exception, it's somehow an "SDK" (it contains the MinGW compiler, not only the Qt libraries). Anyway, have you installed a compiler and solve the issue?

Comment: No, I don't know how! I tried build-essential but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: _apt-get install_ is part of the command and you might need root, so you might need to add _sudo_ in front of the command: _sudo apt-get install build-essential_

Comment: Oh yes I know, it actually worked but I mean I don't know hot to indicate to Qt Creator the new compiler. Actually I don't know what I installed by running this command.

Comment: That should install gcc c and c++ compilers, standard libraries, make and maybe some other tools, see in the Creator's kits menu if it can detect a c++ compiler.

Comment: Look, the problem is still not solved. In the "Kits" tab, here is what I get: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2013/37/1379017175-qt.png